# DisallowNull for method parameters

Tags: c#, attributes

I've recently stumbled upon the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` namespace and the `DisallowNull` attribute. If I understand it correctly you should be able to decorate a parameter with it and Visual Studio should show a warning or error if you try to pass null to said parameter.

I.e.

```
void Test([DisallowNull] string str) { }

Test(null); //should generate some sort of alarm or shriek
```

But I don't see it happening in my project. What am I missing?

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/ and similar

Comment: @canton7, I think you're missing the point by a mile, I am aware of the PLAN TO ERADICATE THE NULLS by Microsoft™ but I'm not using a non-nullable context, I can pass null to that string just fine. My question, if you read it again, is about how does this attribute work because, currently, it's not doing anything, at all.

Comment: You need to have NRT's enabled, which the article describes. Even then that attribute is only for very specialised contexts, most of the time using `string` (instead of `string?`) is what you want

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis

Comment: That attribute exists, along with some others listed in my last link, to help out with telling the nullable reference type machinery about weird edge cases which can't be described by appending `?` to types. It's not what you think it is, it's not used in the way your question suggests, and it does need NRTs to be enabled. If you're not familiar with NRTs then start with introductory articles such as my first link: it's likely you'll never need `DisallowNull`, and if you do, see my last link.

Comment: @canton7, aye, fair enough - that was my bad for outing you like that, my apologies! I didn't see anything in the first article about attributes, which is why I dissed you, but in your defense I never did learn to read.

Answer (score 3):

I. Ensure that nullable contex is enabled and langversion is 8.0 or greater in your csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

II.Check code:

[image]

III. `[DisallowNull]` is not needed for concrete types. `[DisallowNull]` with `string` will have the same warning as just `string`. You can use more simple string type.

IV. Use `[AllowNull]` and `[DisallowNull]` for unconstrained generic types (c#8)

V. You can use `T?` as alternative for `[AllowNull] T` for for unconstrained generic types (from c#9)
see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/unconstrained-type-parameter-annotations